# Prevent a table from update queries for 20 seconds. possible?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers

Here is the problem,
I have a PHP file **called at every second for 20 seconds**. If I write a query to update a table that will be executed 20 times. But **I want it to be updated only once of 20 calls**. After 20 seconds the **table need to be restored for further updates**. How can I accomplish this? Is it anything like trigger to **automatically prevent it for certain period of time**?

```
I have tried something so far,
```

1. I kept a record in a table updating current timestamp, I'm checking the timestamp for the next call, If it exceeds 20 seconds, i'm updating it, else just passing the updating script. It will work, but any more efficient methods?

Comment: Let us know what version of php you are using.

Comment: PHP 5.3.10-1 ubuntu3.10

Comment: why not just set a session value that indicates the last time (timestamp) that the update was completed. If the current timestamp - session timestamp = less than 20, ignore the request else process it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fun and interesting method where by on PHP 5.3 you can use APC cache to store a variable for 20 seconds and given that it does not exist run your query. This would change in php 5.5 with PHPs adoption of a different caching method.

```
if(!$value = apc_fetch('key')) { 
    // Run your query and store the updated key
    apc_store('key', true, 20);  
}
```

The boring and dull method but solidly future proof is to use a session variable to effectively do the same and just check that its within the 20 second limit.

```
if(strtotime($_SESSION['timer']) > strtotime("-20 seconds")) {
    // run your query and update the timer with the update time.
    $_SESSION['timer'] = date();
}
```